# SQLite trigger always fire

Tags: sqlite, triggers, insert

I would insert in a uni field table an item if it don't exist; for this I have a simple trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Insert_Producer
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON Producers
    WHEN NEW.Producer NOT IN (SELECT Producer FROM Producers)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Producers values(NEW.Producer);
END
```

But it does not work and I am not able to find why.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the table `Producers` has other columns than `Producer` too.
If so, then this statement would throw an error:

```
INSERT INTO Producers values(NEW.Producer);
```

You should mention in the statement the column that will receive the value `NEW.Producer`:

```
INSERT INTO Producers(Producer) values(NEW.Producer);
```

Even if you do make this change, the trigger would not do what you expect, because there is nothing there to abort the insertion of the new row if the value already exists in the table.

But you don't need this trigger.
All you have to do is define a [`UNIQUE constraint`](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#unique_constraints) for the column `Producer` and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I found the working trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Insert_Producer
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON Producers
BEGIN
    SELECT
    CASE 
    WHEN NEW.Producer IN (SELECT Producer FROM Producers) THEN
    RAISE(IGNORE)
    END;
END;
```

My be it is not the best but the table is very little.